# How to load *.hdr files using python

Tags: python, hdrimages

I would like to read an environment map in *.hdr file format. It seems that very popular libraries doesn't support .hdr file reading, for example, OpenCV, PIL etc.. So how to read a .hdr file into a numpy array?

Answer (score 6):

I found [ImageIO](http://imageio.github.io) very useful. It can handle many image file formats including .hdr images. Here is the list: [ImageIO Formats](https://imageio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/formats.html)

It can be easily installed using easy_install or pip.

Comment: When I try to load an hrd-image using the imageio module in Python 3 I get the error message `ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'`. Do you know what that means or how to solve it?

Comment: It means that you did not specify the format imageIO should use when reading the file and the auto format detection is coming up with empty. Try running it again with `format='HDR-FI'` as an argument. This will most likely tell you that the FreeImage library is not installed and then it will tell you how to install it. (Spoiler alert: you install it by running `imageio.plugins.freeimage.download()`). After that, it should work.

Comment: I get that prompt, but am unable to download the library because the SSL certificate fails to verify

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I was trying to load a MRI image in .hdr format using `format='HDR-FI'` it was returning `Could not load bitmap <path to image>: : RGBE read error`

But if you type `imageio.show_formats()` it returns a list of formats including "ITK - Insight Segmentation and Registration Toolkit", where it shows that it can handle .hdr images as well.

So my alternative was to use:

```
pip install itk

hdr_path = "<path to image>"
img = imageio.imread(hdr_path, 'ITK') # returns a tuple

img = np.array(img) # transforms to numpy array
```